# Server hanging, can't connect to site until AWS instance is restarted

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, node.js

Our website has been having down time issues lately which seems to be caused by a lack of server resources considering the site crashes only when the servers cpu utilization reaches 100%. During this time the cpu credit balance also drops down to 0.

The only way to get the site back up and running is to go into AWS and restart our t2 micro instance, this causes CPU utilization to drop down and credit balance to go back up. Restarting the node process hasn't been an option since I can't ssh into the server.

We had some scripts that were running on an hourly basis, and some calls constantly being made by quickbooks that we thought were causing this problem but we experienced another crash even after fixing these problems.

I have tried looking through the nginx access logs and nginx error logs but I still cant determine what could be causing the problem. Here are the logs during the time's our server crashed.

Error log:

```
2018/07/06 21:20:10 [error] 1296#1296: *27123 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 65.95.163.215, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "www"
2018/07/06 21:20:10 [error] 1296#1296: *27110 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 205.194.127.36, server: , request: "GET /views/submitforfunding/paymentoptions/paymentoptions.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/views/submitforfunding/paymentoptions/paymentoptions.js", host: ""
2018/07/06 21:20:10 [error] 1296#1296: *27144 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 69.162.124.237, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "", referrer: ""
2018/07/06 21:20:10 [error] 1296#1296: *27145 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 69.162.124.237, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "", referrer: ""
2018/07/06 21:20:10 [error] 1296#1296: *27123 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 65.95.163.215, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/favicon.ico", host: "", referrer: "https://"
2018/07/06 21:20:15 [alert] 1296#1296: *27126 open socket #22 left in connection 10
2018/07/06 21:20:15 [alert] 1296#1296: *27128 open socket #14 left in connection 18
2018/07/06 21:20:15 [alert] 1296#1296: *27119 open socket #16 left in connection 23
2018/07/06 21:20:15 [alert] 1296#1296: *27131 open socket #24 left in connection 28
2018/07/06 21:20:15 [alert] 1296#1296: *27121 open socket #4 left in connection 30
2018/07/06 21:20:15 [alert] 1296#1296: aborting
2018/07/06 21:22:53 [error] 1311#1311: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 69.162.124.237, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "", referrer: ""
2018/07/06 21:25:20 [error] 1314#1314: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 63.143.42.253, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "", referrer: "http://"
2018/07/06 21:25:27 [crit] 1314#1314: *4 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 63.143.42.253, server: blog., request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "blog.", referrer: "http://blog."
2018/07/06 21:25:36 [error] 1314#1314: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 69.162.124.237, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "", referrer: "http://www."
2018/07/06 21:25:46 [error] 1314#1314: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 65.95.163.215, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: ""
2018/07/06 21:25:47 [error] 1314#1314: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 65.95.163.215, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/favicon.ico", host: "", referrer: "https:///"
2018/07/06 21:25:52 [error] 1314#1314: *16 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 69.162.124.237, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "", referrer: "http://www."
2018/07/06 21:26:00 [error] 1314#1314: *18 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 96.20.89.42, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "www."
2018/07/06 21:26:00 [error] 1314#1314: *18 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 96.20.89.42, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/favicon.ico", host: "www.", referrer: "https://www./"
2018/07/06 21:26:02 [error] 1314#1314: *21 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 65.95.163.215, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8020/", host: "www."
```

Access log:

```
165.227.83.148 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:05:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
138.197.150.151 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:05:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:06:21 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:06:42 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:07:30 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:07:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:07:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:08:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:08:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:08:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
54.67.10.127 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:09:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
165.227.83.148 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:09:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
128.199.195.156 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:10:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:10:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
146.185.143.14 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:10:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
165.227.83.148 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:11:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:11:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:11:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:12:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:12:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:12:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:13:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:13:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:13:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:13:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:14:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:14:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:15:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:15:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:15:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:16:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:16:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:16:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:17:14 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:17:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:18:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:18:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:18:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:19:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
216.244.66.234 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET /tag/failure/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
180.76.188.144 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "-"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 262 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
65.95.163.215 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
205.194.127.36 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET /views/submitforfunding/paymentoptions/paymentoptions.js HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)"
180.76.15.151 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET /tag/venturx/ HTTP/1.1" 500 262 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
65.95.163.215 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:20:10 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "https://www./" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:22:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:22:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
65.95.163.215 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
65.95.163.215 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:47 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "https:///" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:25:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
96.20.89.42 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
96.20.89.42 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:00 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "https://www./" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
65.95.163.215 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
65.95.163.215 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:02 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "https://www./" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
146.185.241.50 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:18 +0000] "GET /2017/07/28/survey-product-market-fit-24-hours/ HTTP/1.0" 502 182 "https://blog./2017/07/28/survey-product-market-fit-24-hours/#comment-1457/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
146.185.241.50 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 502 182 "https://blog./" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
146.185.241.50 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 502 182 "https:///" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.1; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
63.143.42.253 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://blog." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:36 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
69.162.124.237 - - [06/Jul/2018:21:26:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "http://www." "Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; UptimeRobot/2.0; http://www.uptimerobot.com/)"
```

The access logs shows the uptime robot hammering away at our server every 30 seconds or so but I don't believe this is the root of the problem since this uptime robot has been configured this way long before we started having issues with our site.

If someone could point out any issues in our logs that I should be looking at or if there is anything I could look into, it would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Here's the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    client_max_body_size 800M;
    ssl_protocols            TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  24h;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8020/;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should be looking at using a larger instance or using Auto Scaling.

Comment: You need to monitor to determine which piece of software is using your CPU, perhaps by benchmarking on a test instance. You will need a larger instance, auto scaling to more instances, and you could look at t2 unlimited if you occasionally run out of CPU credits.

Comment: Have you tried staying connected and watching the output of htop so you can see what specifically is using all the resources when the system is failing?    Any chance  your system is compromised and some malware is using all your resources?

Comment: Looking into a larger instance might be something I have to do but I don't see why I'm running into these issues all of a sudden. The cpu usage just spikes to 100% and I haven't been able to pinpoint why.

@Zoredache Thanks for the idea. I'll be keeping an eye out to see what could be eating up all the resources. I don't think we're having a malware issue, but what should I do to confirm this?

Comment: set some monitoring alerts on instance and login to server once it cross threshold (say 70 % cpu usages). Find out process consuming for cpu using top commond. Also check number of active connections on server with netstat.

Comment: Did any of the people above me even look at the logfiles?? There isn't a single 200 response code in there, your server is returning a 301 redirect to absolutely everything, until the client gets bored of your little Nginx merry go round and times out. At this point you get a 499 or 502 depending upon where that request ended up. Show me your Nginx config.

Comment: @miknik We redirect http to https. The 502 occurs when the instance is rebooted but before the node app is restarted. Ill edit the config into the main post.